# Build Python executable with Julia dependencies

Tags: julia, pyinstaller, juliacall

I'm trying to make a Python application using PyQt5 that calls functions from Julia. In my main script I am using the juliacall lib to access the Julia functions I need.

My problem comes after I build the main.exe using pyinstaller. When I try to run it, I get the following error:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

So far I've tried:

- Reinstall julia and its dependencies.
- Create a new env.
- Using python's "julia" lib instead of "juliacall" (even worse).

Before anyone asks, I have to use these Julia libs because they are models coded only in that language...